# How is it that #define does not require one to specify the variable type?

Tags: objective-c

Why is it that this code works?

```
// in a constants file:

#define ADFadeOutSpeed 1.1



// then, later, in another file:

-(void)fadeOut:(UIView *)sender{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:ADFadeOutSpeed];
    sender.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I was expecting that the compiler would complain that ADFadeOutSpeed was not strongly typed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because #define doesn't create a variable or object, it's a compiler command that says 'replace all instances of foo with bar' -- so what's happening, quit eliterally, is that ADFadeOutSpeed is *read* as 1.1 every time it shows in your code.  The compiler doesn't see:

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:ADFadeOutSpeed];
```

it sees

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.1];
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was not quite clear on the nature of #define being at the pre-compilation stage.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply text substitution when preprocessed. That is, the text is substituted before compilation happens.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is a C pre-compiler macro and not a variable. You're specifying that the string `ADFadeOutSpeed` will be replaced with the string `1.1` before your code is compiled. You get no compiler warning because as far as the compiler itself is concerned the expression it is evaluating is `[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.1];` and it interprets the `1.1` as a literal.

Comment: Thank you also for your correct answer. All were upvoted, RonLugge gets the accepted for being first.